# How to make a CompletionHandler with Firebase Swift 3

Tags: xcode, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, completionhandler

I need to get some informations from Firebase to out it on `UIViewCell`. But the problem is that the function return before he get all the value. I know that's because it's asynchronous, i tried to make a completion Handler like that:

```
static func hardProcessingWithString(input: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: String) -> Void) {
    Database.database().reference().child("Player_1").observe(.value) {
        (firDataSnapshot) in
        completion((firDataSnapshot.value as? String)!)    
    }
}
```

This is how i try to get the value :

```
var myVar: String!
hardProcessingWithString(input: "commands"){
        (result: String) in
        myVar = result
}
```

I get this error when I call the function:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x102e292b0) to 'NSString' (0x102434c60).

Here's my Firebase database:

[image: DataBase from Firebase]

Or if you know how to make a Promise with Firebase let me know!

Comment: show us database structre of child "Player_1". Error not in completion handler, but in types. Something like screenshot of db

Comment: is firDataSnapshot.value actually a String? Could you debug that value?

Comment: @petul Yes it's a String !

Comment: @Max0u could Normally it returns a dictionary though. could you try let value = firDataSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary. Then you can access your value like you normally would in a Dictionary

Comment: Please show us the code that calls your `hardProcessingWithString` function...

Comment: Now the problem is that myVar is always equal to nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Step 1:

Create a swift file like Constant.swift. Then place the below code inside it

```
typealias DownloadComplete = () -> ()
```

## Step 2:

Create a function where you want.

```
func hardProcessingWithString(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
Database.database().reference().child("Player_1").observe (.value, with: { (firDataSnapshot) in

// put your code here

completed()
})
}
```

## Step 3:

when you call above method in your code

```
 hardProcessingWithString() {
    // you can get the result here
}
```

Comment: Read his "Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x102e292b0) to 'NSString' (0x102434c60).". The problem is not in completion handler organiazing.

Comment: @Alwin But how can I return the value in the fonction ? I want to get the value of firDataSnapshot

Comment: create a global variable and set getters and setters